# Following a proposal displays the "You've committed..." popup

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, commitment-phase

Unless I'm just remembering the text wrong after clicking to follow proposals...  I remember it as "You're now following this proposal..."

[Not yet! http://www.sqeq.com/content/image/MSO_Area51EarlyCommit.png](http://www.sqeq.com/content/image/MSO_Area51EarlyCommit.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oops, we had a typo in our javascript. It's fixed now. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, surely it is!